# Why is IntelliJ telling me that reference can not be null in this situation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is the code I have:

```
private void foo(Bar bar) {
    Session session = null;
    Class entityClazz = null;
    try {
        entityClazz = Hibernate.getClass(bar);
        if (bar != null) {
```

And IntelliJ will warn me for the last statement above with the message:

> Condition 'bar != null' is always 'true'. This inspection
>   analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions
>   that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically
>   proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability
>   contract violations.

When I delete the statement:

```
entityClazz = Hibernate.getClass(bar);
```

the warning will be gone.

What is going on in IntelliJ 's mind here, what is stopping from bar being null?

Comment: I guess, because `Hibernate.getClass(bar)` will throw a NullPointerException if `bar` is null and thus the `if` will never be reached in that case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did not see any NPE being thrown in the code but maybe I missed it..

Comment: Check whether `Hibernate.getClass` has a `@NotNull` on its parameter.

Comment: BTW IntelliJ has a list of commonly used methods it "knows" should be @NotNull (Not sure where it stores this info but Imagine it's an XML file somewhere)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Documentation is here and I do not see any NutNull: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getClass(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Looks like Idea is able to analyze Hibernate.getClass to see that it throws Exception if bar is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the hibernate documentation, this is what getClass() method in org.hibernate.Hibernate class does.

```
public static Class getClass(Object proxy) {
        if ( proxy instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
            return ( ( HibernateProxy ) proxy ).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                    .getImplementation()
                    .getClass();
        }
        else {
            return proxy.getClass();
        }
    }
```

As per the documentation `HibernateException` is thrown in case of a null parameter, which is an extended class of `NestableRuntimeException` also a `RuntimeException`.

Intellij is able to analyze this, using its code inspections it is easily found that the loc

```
entityClazz = Hibernate.getClass(bar);
```

would throw an NPE. If it throws an NPE, the if condition statement is never reached, as NestableRuntimeException are unchecked exceptions.

You can place the if condition above the Hibernate.getClass(bar) which would be ideal for a null safe method.

Hope this clears.

References

[Hibernate Documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.1/org/hibernate/Hibernate.java#Hibernate.getClass%28java.lang.Object%29)

[Code Analysis - Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/code-analysis.html)

[Code Inspection - Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/code-inspection.html#d1558064e451)

Comment: Where did you find 'As per the documentation HibernateException is thrown in case of a null parameter' ?

Comment: Well, no documents say that it is because of NPE. Refer the Javadocs but Check the initialize() method in org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer class